# Tangential acceleration of a two-dimensional rotating mass point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

An object moves on the trajectory
$$\vec{r}(t)=c\cdot\big(\theta t,\sin{(\theta t)}\big).$$

I know how to calculate the vector of acceleration (second derivative of $\vec{r}$).
$$\vec{a}(t)=c\cdot\big(0,-\theta\sin{(\theta t)}\big)$$

I also know how to calculate the amount of the acceleration vector $a(t)=|\vec{a}(t)|=c\cdot\theta\cdot\sin{(\theta t)}$.

**How do I calculate tangential acceleration?**

Comment: What are your components? Polar (radial distance, angle) or cartesian (x,y)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute the tangent unit vector (computed from the velocity as $\vec{v} ( t ) / | \vec{v} ( t ) | $). Then take the dot product with your acceleration to obtain its tangential component.